# Require.js: How do I Tell Require Not to Prepend a Forward Slash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am building a small page using require.js.  I'm a js noob in some ways, and am not up to speed on the current ecosystem of tools, hence my basic question about require.  I have a js file I want to fetch from an api.  Here's what I have:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/api/MyFiless/GetFile?fileName=',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'CommonJquery-2.0.3',
...
});
```

The problem is this requests

```
/api/MyFiles/GetFile?fileName=/CommonJquery-2.0.3.js
```

How do I tell require to request:

```
/api/MyFiles/GetFile?fileName=CommonJquery-2.0.3.js
```

In general I want to fetch many js files this way, how do I do this?

Comment: Your problem is from https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/8b477f608601bfcd9b5fa7ab333de310278dee65/require.js#L1250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like RequireJS is ensuring that the `baseUrl` property ends with a trailing slash:

(Line 1247 in require.js: [source](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js))

```
        configure: function (cfg) {
            //Make sure the baseUrl ends in a slash.
            if (cfg.baseUrl) {
                if (cfg.baseUrl.charAt(cfg.baseUrl.length - 1) !== '/') {
                    cfg.baseUrl += '/';
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks redmallard and thanks megawac. Thats the underlying cause.  I had to update the paths a little bit using that knowledge.  Now Im on the the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

As @redmallard and I mentioned your issue is a defined behaviour in the requirejs api. If you don't want to hack up requirejs (which may be approriate) to fix your issue you may have to make your config as below. Although less clean, this will create valid urls

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/api/MyFiless/GetFile',
  paths: {
    jquery: '?fileName=CommonJquery-2.0.3'
  }
});
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/AjIMuge/1